# Objective-C -- Subclass of delegate in subclass

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, oop, delegates

This is a fairly complicated inheritance hierarchy, so bear with me (I've tried to simplify things rather than state the exact case I am using which is even more complex):-

Let's say I create a subclass of `UITextField` called `TextField` which is my own custom enhanced general-purpose textfield. Now, in order to provide this enhanced functionality, in the `init` method of `TextField`, I set `super.delegate = self` so that all the delegate methods from `UITextField` are sent to `TextField`. `TextField` implements the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol and receives those delegate methods to do something interesting.

However, in turn, I want to make it so that `TextField` has it's *own* delegate. So I create a new protocol called `TextFieldDelegate` (note the lack of `UI`-prefix!) and give `TextField` an ivar `id<TextFieldDelegate> __weak delegate` with corresponding property so that other classes can receive delegate methods from `TextField`.

I hope you're still with me, because I haven't done anything too complex so far. But let's say that now, I create another custom subclass of `TextField`, let's call it `PasswordTextField` (in real life, one probably wouldn't need to create a subclass just to implement a password functionality, but let's assume that there is some fairly sophisticated implementation that would require this).

Let's also assume that I want to make it so that `PasswordTextField` (which like `TextField` has a delegate property) is able to send an enhanced set of delegate methods. For example, maybe it can send a method `passwordIsSecure` which is sent once a password has reached a required level of complexity. Now since this behaviour that wouldn't be found in the regular `TextField`, I create a new protocol: `PasswordTextFieldDelegate <TextFieldDelegate>` which defines the new delegate methods for `PasswordTextField` *and* inherits all of the delegate methods sent by `TextField`.

The problem is: how do I do implement this in `PasswordTextField`? Things that don't work:

**Inheritance**

I cannot simply inherit the delegate from `TextField`, because `TextField`'s delegate conforms only to `TextFieldDelegate` and not `PasswordTextFieldDelegate`, so I can't send methods like `[delegate passwordIsSecure]` because `TextFieldDelegate` has no such method.

**Overriding ivar**

I could try declaring an ivar in `PasswordTextField` called delegate, but the compiler complains that this is a duplicate declaration, because of course there is already an ivar called delegate in the superclass, so this doesn't work either*.

**Modifying the superclass**

I could go back to the `TextField` class and redefine the delegate to implement both `TextFieldDelegate` **and** `PasswordTextFieldDelegate`, but this seems messy and tells `TextField` that it can send `PasswordTextFieldDelegate` methods, which of course, it can't!

I haven't tried this one, simply because it seems to break every sensible coding rule in the book.

In summary, there must be some way of doing this such that a subclass of a class can have it's own delegate that's a sub-delegate of the superclass's delegate and for all of this to fit together nicely, but I just can't figure it out! Any ideas?

(* As a side issue, I don't understand why the compiler complains when `PasswordTextField` declares a "duplicate" ivar named delegate, but doesn't complain when `TextField` declares an ivar named delegate which is presumably a duplicate of `UITextField`'s property called delegate!)

Comment: may be im just hitting in the dark.. but wouldnt it help if you just re-declare the @property of your delegate as id<NewChildProtocol> and have its own synthesize? i think it will work. mebbe ill give it a try after a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITextField delegate ivar is named _delegate, not delegate. Hence why you get away with declaring it again in TextField, but not in PasswordTextField.

As for your delegate inheritance problem. I'm not sure ObjectiveC supports what you want.

You may just have to type your delegate 'id', instead of 'id<TextFieldDelegate>'. Then you could override setDelegate and ensure that the delegate passed in conformsToProtocol. However, you would lose your compile time checks here and only have the runtime check of conformsToProtocol

Comment: Thanks for clarification of _delegate behaviour.

I did consider just setting the type as id -- I forgot to include it in my list of possible solutions but as you say it loses compile-time checks, so I would have thought there would be a better solution?

Comment: Well you can't have the best of both worlds (well I don't think you can.... maybe some languages are better at this) ..... I came from Java, and I missed the strong Type safety at first. But Objective-C is so much more flexible than Java, that I can live with these little quirks - and enjoy all the other greatness of this language. However, I only use 'id' if I really can't give something a type.

Comment: can I get a Code example?

Answer (score 1):

So, there! works.. and manages to have the compile-time warnings as well..

SimpleParent.h

```
@protocol Parentprotocol <NSObject>

@end

@interface SimpleParent : NSObject {
    id<Parentprotocol> obj;
}

@property (retain) id<Parentprotocol> obj;

@end
```

SimpleParent.m

```
#import "SimpleParent.h"

@implementation SimpleParent
@synthesize obj;

@end
```

SimpleChild.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SimpleParent.h"

@protocol SimpleChildProtocol <Parentprotocol>


@end

@interface SimpleChild : NSObject

@property (assign) id<SimpleChildProtocol> obj;

@end
```

SimpleChild.m

```
#import "SimpleChild.h"

@implementation SimpleChild
@synthesize obj;

@end
```

Comment: That works, until SimpleChild needs to also inherit from SimpleParent. Is there a way of working it so inheritance works from both the class and protocol at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

It is a quite confusing question, so forgive me if I'm missing the point, but it seems like your three different inheritance levels each have different requirements from their delegate, ergo each delegate would have to conform to a different protocol, so would it be a solution to hold each level's delegate as a differently named ivar, and as a different reference?

For example, your base class would have its `delegate`, which you have decided will be assigned to the first inheriting subclass. This has it's own delegate, called `level1delegate`, and the next level down has *another* delegate, called `level2delegate`. You could of course set all three of these to the same object if that object conformed to all three protocols.

Basically, there's no rule that says a delegate has to be called "delegate", so don't tear yourself apart trying not to break it.

Comment: I imagine he is used to other languages which would allow you to do this. Eg in Java I could declare an instance variable to be of a particular interface (i.e. protocol) and in the subclass, I could redefine the instance variable to be of more specialised type (i.e. a extension of the interface). However Java is strongly staticly typed

Comment: Yes, prior to developing in Objective-C I was a Java developer!